# Running tests in IntelliJ ClassNotFoundException

Tags: scala, testing, intellij-idea, specs2

I tried many different run configs, but whatever I do I get this exception when running specs2 tests in IntelliJ for scala.

It always fails to find a class that ends with a `$` sign. I checked - and there really is no such class file. There's AppControllerIT.class and lots of classes like AppControllerIT$innerFunctionOrclass.clas, but not AppControllerIT$.class

Any ideas?

Thanks!

```
com.haha.market.api.e2e.controllers.AppControllerIT$

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.haha.market.api.e2e.controllers.AppControllerIT$


STACKTRACE
  java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
  java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
  sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
  java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
  org.specs2.reflect.Classes$$anonfun$loadClassEither$1.apply(Classes.scala:140)
  org.specs2.reflect.Classes$$anonfun$loadClassEither$1.apply(Classes.scala:140)
  org.specs2.control.ActionT$$anonfun$safe$1.apply(ActionT.scala:89)
  org.specs2.control.ActionT$$anonfun$reader$1$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(ActionT.scala:80)
  org.specs2.control.Status$.safe(Status.scala:100)
```

Comment: did you try cleaning and rebuilding everything? Are all your sources being compiled? It is indeed a weird error.

Comment: @DanielL., yes, tried cleaning everything and rebuilding - nothing helps. And it's indeed an IntelliJ issue, because tests work if I type mvn test in the command line

Comment: Then I got nothing. I wuld try different SDK's just for kicks, maybe removing and re-adding the functionality by small steps. :-(

Answer (score 1):

Classes with `$` signs at the end are generate from compiled Scala objects. This means you may have an object defined similar to this:

```
package com.haha.market.api.e2e.controllers

object AppControllerIT {
}
```

From your error, it seems that an older compiled artifact or a library (?) is *polluting* your classpath. First, try cleaning up the project (`mvn clean` or `sbt clean`). Next, try to clean any libraries you have in your project inside IntelliJ. IntelliJ sometimes caches multiple versions of the same libraries which may cause confusion during runtime. To clean those up go to "File -> Project Structure" in IntelliJ and manually delete any duplicated libraries you may have.